# Rare AdMob partial ban for no apparent reason?

Tags: android, admob

This email is to alert you that one of your applications is not currently in compliance with our AdMob program policies and as a result, ad serving has been disabled to your application.

Issue ID#: 20435942

Ad serving has been disabled to: LG G4 Flashlight (com.example.example)

Action required: Check all other remaining applications in your account for compliance.

Current account status: Active

Violation explanation

As stated in our program policies, apps displaying Google ads should provide substantial and useful information to the user. Users should be able to easily navigate through the app to find what products, goods, or services are promised. Examples of misguided navigation include, but are not limited to:

- False claims of downloadable or streaming content
- Linking to content that does not exist
- Redirecting users to irrelevant and/or misleading pages
- Text on a page unrelated to the topic and/or business model of the
  app.

For more information, please review Google’s Webmaster quality guidelines and the AdMob program policies.

Action required: Check account for compliance
While ad serving has been disabled to the above app, your AdMob account remains active. We suggest that you take the time to review the rest of your applications to ensure that they’re in compliance with our policies, and to monitor your apps accordingly to reduce the likelihood of future policy emails from us. Additionally, please note that our team reserves the right to disable accounts at any time if we continue to see violations occurring.

Appeals
If you wish to appeal this disabling then you can do so by using our appeal form.

Thank you for your cooperation.

Sincerely,

The Google AdMob Team

*The application contains a single non-obtrusive banner ad and no interstitials or misleading ads. Only the default AdMob ads are used. How is this app in violation of the above mentioned reasons?*

Answer (score 0):

The case of "flashlight" apps is mentioned in the [google admob implementation guide](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2936217?hl=en):

> You should also avoid placing ads on an app screen when users do not
>   have their attention on the screen. In utility apps, where the phone
>   is used as a tool, the user’s focus will often be off-screen and
>   accidental clicks are more likely to occur. For example, if you have a
>   utility app like a “flashlight” app, ads should not be on the screen
>   while the flashlight is in use. However, you may consider placing an
>   ad on the flashlight app’s menu screen, especially if the menu screen
>   is separate and the user’s focus is on the screen while navigating the
>   menu.

==> make sure no banner is shown while the app's flashlight is in use!

Comment: Yet most of the top flashlight applications in the google play store have banner ads enabled continuously.

Comment: Well, the google guidelines say you shouldn't do it this way and you got an email from google saying your app is not compliant with the guidelines. That other apps do it this way and didn't got banned is unfortunately not a guarantee that this is now an accepted way of implementing admob.

Comment: i have been banned, and i suppose is beacuse of this, google admob is really trash i will remove my ads from my flashlights and try to appeal because i have other kind of apps